# What was that? Chat with an "expert"

Tags: discussion, chat

Today half an hour ago I visited MSE and I was proposed to chat with an "expert". I tried to discuss some questions about von Neumann algebras that botherd me, but this was not an expert I needed. This was not an expert at all and I think this was just a bot. But why is it here?

Comment: The bot would have a greater success if it didn't start typing _immediately_ after one presses enter. It feels fishy right away, even before reading what it had to say. They had to make random delays within a 2-4 seconds range.

Comment: meta.SO: [What is “chat with an expert”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174407/what-is-chat-with-an-expert)

Comment: I personally assumed it was a new feature and ignored it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The bot is here to fool people as 01 Apr is April Fool's Day. I chatted with the machine just now myself for about 5 min. This is just part of SE's way of having some fun with its users. Everyone, enjoy!

Comment: Oh boy, I even didn't know today's date... completely lost in time!

Comment: Wait until you find out that it's not actually April 1!

Comment: The annoying thing is that even if you click "never", it still comes back...

Comment: It was so annoying that I didn't even bother to click.

Answer (score 19):

Sorry, I don't know too much about von Neumann algebras. However, I was very pleased to be able to talk to you. I apologize for not being able to help further. StackExchange has elected me to help with users on the mainsite with more professional one-on-one assistance.

Comment: @anon, don't apologiese you have good expertize in other branches of math

Comment: Whose pretty face is that in Expert's avatar?

Answer (score 4):

I noticed it was a bot from the beginning. I asked it and it admitted :)
I proposed a date/talk with my own bots ;)

Comment: so this is you? $$$$ xkcd.com/632/

Comment: Same. We had a little Turing test. It lasted about 10 seconds...